Write a piece of Quine code that can be excuted by both C and Python
Write a piece of code that is compatible with both C and Python compilers/interpreters, which can output its own source code.
Quine is quite easy, but how about this double language version?
Hint:
To make your code can be executed by both language compilers/interpreters, here's an example:
#ifdef THIS_IS_PYTHON
print("Hello World!")
#endif

#ifdef THIS_IS_PYTHON
"""
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}

#ifdef THIS_IS_PYTHON
"""
#endif
```

